# using "insert into" command to mark a check box as yes

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert, vba, ms-access-2010

Does the insert into command work for check boxes I have tried to change it a few times using INSERT INTO command the rest of the columns perform the function except the check box.

```
INSERT INTO Record ( Member, Date, Location, Movie, In, Out)
VALUES ('5', '11/12/2010', 'A1Z', '387654321', 'Yes', 'No');
```

Tried to run with true false but still not working still getting a syntax error

Comment: can you add the code you are trying?

Comment: can you please elaborate and post your code if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, INSERT works for CheckBoxes.  Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( FldA, FldB, ChkBox )
SELECT "A" AS Expr1, "B" AS Expr2, True AS Expr6;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the error.  I can tell you that this `INSERT` statement successfully added one row to the `Record` table created from the `CREATE TABLE` statement below:

```sql
INSERT INTO Record
    (
        Member,
        [Date],
        Location,
        Movie,
        [In],
        [Out]
    )
VALUES
    (
        '5',
        #2010-11-12#,
        'A1Z',
        '387654321',
        True,
        False
    );
```

One possible complication is that `Date`, `In`, and `Out` are all [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  I expected `Record` would also be a reserved word, but apparently it's not.  I enclosed those field names in square brackets to avoid confusing the db engine.  But I'm not certain those names contributed to your problem.

Some other considerations ...

- If your `Date` field is Date/Time datatype, use `#` delimiters (instead of quotes) for the value you insert into that field.
- If `In` and `Out` are YesNo datatype, give them True or False without quotes.  The corresponding integer values, -1 for True and 0 for False, will also work.

This is the statement I used to create my `Record` table in Access 2007:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Record
    (
        Member TEXT(255),
        [Date] DATETIME,
        Location TEXT(255),
        Movie TEXT(255),
        [In] YESNO,
        [Out] YESNO
    );
```